# Modifying Underlying Buffer of open_memstream

Tags: c, memorystream

I am implementing an HTTP server in which I receive bytes till `\r\n\r\n` and store them in a stream:

```
    char *request_buffer;
    size_t request_bytes = 0, recv_bytes;
    FILE *request_stream = open_memstream(&request_buffer, &request_bytes);

    bool headers_received = false;

    while (!headers_received) {
        char buf[BUFSIZ] = {0};
        recv_bytes = recv(client_socketfd, buf, BUFSIZ - 1, NULL);
        if (recv_bytes == -1) {
            perror("recv");
            continue;
        } else if (recv_bytes == 0) {
            printf("Connection closed\n");
            break;
        }
        fprintf(request_stream, "%s", buf);
        if (strstr(buf, "\r\n\r\n") != NULL)
            headers_received = true;
    }
```

Now, I need to keep the stream open in order to receive further requests from the same client (HTTP/1.1 pipelining). However, I also need to parse the received headers. So, I have two options:

Either copy `request_buffer` then tokenize:

```
   char request[request_bytes + 1];
   fread(request, sizeof (char), request_bytes, request_stream);
   request[request_bytes] = '\0';
   char *request_save_ptr, *line_save_ptr, *line;
   line = strtok_r(request, "\r\n", &request_save_ptr);
   char *method = strtok_r(line, " ", &line_save_ptr);
   if (strcmp(method, "GET") == 0) {
//.. continue parsing
```

Or tokenize `request_buffer` directly:

```
   char *request_save_ptr, *line_save_ptr, *line;
   line = strtok_r(request_buffer, "\r\n", &request_save_ptr);
   char *method = strtok_r(line, " ", &line_save_ptr);
   if (strcmp(method, "GET") == 0) {
//.. continue parsing
```

Can I use `strtok` directly on `request_buffer`? I know that `strtok` modifies the passed `char *`, and my gut feeling is that this could interfere with `open_memstream`, but I have found nothing to this effect in `open_memstream` man page; and, well, the code does work correctly. I don't prefer the "copy then parse" option because I don't want to use double the memory. But if need be, I could go on with this choice since any client is dealt with in a separate `fork()`, so memory isn't that much of an issue.

Thanks

Comment: Describing your code is all but worthless.  Post your actual code, and make your question clear.

Comment: Well, I've described the useful parts of my code.. posting the whole file is discouraged, isn't it? What exactly about my question is unclear? I could clarify.

Comment: `posting the whole file is discouraged, isn't it?` It's encouraged, unless it's super super long - then it's encouraged to simplify it and post the whole file then. I.e. [MCVE] . As may be asking XY question - you ask _only_ about `open_memstream`, which may, or may be, your actual bug. `I could copy the request_buffer and tokenize the copy, but is this really necessary?` but.. why not just close the stream and tokenize then?

Comment: Done editing.  I have no bug, I just _fear_ potential bugs.